# Достижения. Название интервалов времени не согласовано

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

В выпадающем списке достижений не согласовано название групп:

> [image: Достижения]

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky выбран вариант с максимумом голосов на момент установки метки [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использовать вариант:

> Последние 7 дней 
>   Последние 30 дней

Answer (score 1):

Использовать вариант:

> За последние 7 дней 
>   За последние 30 дней

Answer (score 0):

Оставить как есть, ничего не трогать.

Comment: Поясню свой выбор, почему не нужно ничего менять. Приписывать к каждому варианту "за" (за сегодня, за вчера....) не выйдет (потому что "за более старые сообщения" некорректно с точки зрения языка), а кроме того, с точки зрения дизайна некрасиво, когда список/таблица имеет повторяющуюся часть в начале каждого элемента.
Чуть менее хорош вариант сделать два "за", однако мне кажется более элегантным оставить только первое: отсутствующие второго "за" делает переход к фразе "более старые" более плавным: было без "за", потом один раз появилось, потом постепенно ушло на убыль.

Comment: @AK не совсем понимаю тогда, почему Вы не выбрали вариант вовсе без "За".

Comment: Потому что без "за" переход от "вчера" к "последние 30 дней" звучит не очень красиво. А вот переходы от "за последние 7 дней" к "последние 30 дней" и "последние 30 дней" к "более старые" воспринимаются как вполне естественные.

Comment: Хотите -- можно попробовать паралельно задать вопрос в [сообществе по русскому языку](http://rus.stackexchange.com/) и послушать их мнение? Там правда, "сапожники без сапог": у них вообще никто не занимается переводом, всё больше на вопросы из ЕГЭ отвечают.

Comment: Вообще, есть некоторая мешанина: первые два пункта отвечают на вопрос "когда" (вчера, сегодня), потом два отвечают на вопрос "за какой период" и последний отвечает на вопрос "какие". Но воспринимается вполне естественно.