# Невозможность проголосовать за общее сообщение

Tags: поддержка, общие-сообщения

Почему нельзя проголосовать за общее сообщение, несмотря на то, что голоса за него не влияют на репутацию автора?

Вопрос возник в частности из-за желания выразить свою позицию по [предложению](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3595/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE) путем голосования.

Comment: Вы являетесь одним из авторов общего сообщения?

Comment: @cheops не одним, единственным :) Но почему это должно быть важно?

Comment: Помимо репутации за ответы назначаются знаки, ряд из них требует всего двух голосов, например, Возрождение. Вероятно, ограничение введено, чтобы предотвратить голосовать за собственные ответы с целью получения знаков. Я так понимаю, за общие вопросы, в которых вы не участвуете как автор, вы голосовать можете?

Comment: @cheops причина выдачи знаков за общие вопросы тоже не совсем ясна (это наверное надо в отдельной теме обсуждать). За другие общие голосовать могу, насколько я понимаю. Но хотелось именно по упомянутой теме выразить свою позицию через голосование за один из вариантов. Однако, не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Получаемая репутация за ответы в вопросе является лишь дополнением к основному назначению голосования – отделить верные ответы от ошибочных.

Comment: Короче говоря, сделать нормальное голосование, в котором может проголосовать и автор, предлагающий варианты для выбора, средствами SO (вопрос-ответы) не представляется возможным. Так?

Comment: Сейчас голосование работает правильно. Автор сообщения не может голосовать за сообщение. Так задумано изначально, и применяется как к авторским сообщениям, так и к общим.

Comment: Разве это правильно, когда автор голосования не может принять участие в самом голосовании?

Comment: Да, именно! Например, участники не могут видеть, кто именно голосовал, как результат, не ясно, была ли оценка сделана сообществом или же самим автором сообщения, что, в свою очередь, сильно влияет на доверие к самому сообщению.

Comment: Про "сильно влияет" это всё же сильно сказано :) Всего-то один голос плюс/минус. Другой момент голосования на SO ещё и в том, что помимо поднятия одного варианта можно одновременно опустить и другой. Т.е. разница уже может быть 2 голоса на одного участника. Хотя в "классическом" голосовании можно отдать только голос "за", и часто только за единственный вариант.