# 10 вариантов в голосовании

Tags: дефект, поддержка, голосование

Сейчас в [вопросе с голосованием за вопросы кандидатам в модераторы](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9051/178988) есть около 10 вопросов Suvitruf. Однако, как известно, при попытке голосовать за них сразу, голоса будут откатываться системой. Как мы узнаем реальное распределение голосов по ним?

Comment: Можно просто сразу сделать меня модератором (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf сначала придётся за всё ответить!

Comment: [Давно уже говорил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3600/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment11624_3606), что голосование нормальное средствами SO сделать невозможно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ пойдёмте-ка выйдем (╯°益°)╯彡┻━┻

Comment: @αλεχολυτ интересно, в кулуарах, побывать, решаются ли там все вопросы так же как описано правилами, или как в обычной жизни? Может сообщество уже давно прогнило? Больше всего интересно, как поступают с правокаторами  или с неугодными людьми для модераторов сообщества

Comment: Судя по всему, исправлять не будут: «[it's likely that if a person posts multiple answers that they are (or at least should) offer some sort of a different perspective, so legitimately serially upvoting all of them wouldn't make a lot of sense.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151464)»

Comment: Сделать ответы общими? (Вообще-то так и полагается делать при создании голосовалок)

Comment: @AK, ворде бы не поможет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не знаю, просто предложил. Давайте может как раз и попробуем на модераторской теме и посмотрим что будет? Не знаю просто, когда следующий такой удобный случай представится.

Comment: @AK, на вопрос ставить или на ответы?

Comment: @AK, а вообще, может там и так поправили?

Comment: Может и поправили. Нужен ещё один доброволец, который даст с десяток ответов, например, Arhad пусть разберёт свой ответ на вопросы (уж десяток-то наберётся там полноценных вопросов). Suvitruf сделает общими, а Arhad оставит авторство на себе (ну или наоборот, пусть монетку кинут). Выберем день, когда массово заголосуем обоих и посмотрим, кому откатит на следующий день голоса. Как такой эксперимент?